# Python 3: Checking for the length and data type. & Error Fix

Tags: python-3.x, time, format, distance

I am having some problems with my project:
With the code I currently have, I am getting an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Username\Folder\Folder2\design2.py", line 13, in <module>
    elif numberplate3.isaplha():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isaplha'
```

### Here is the code:

```
while True:
import time
numberplate1 = str(input("Enter in the first 2 letters of the numberplate"))
if numberplate1.isalpha():
   print("Verification 1 Success")
   numberplate2 = str(input("Enter in the next 2 chars of the numberplate"))
   if numberplate2.isdigit():
       print("Verification 2 Success")
       numberplate3 = str(input("Enter the last 3 digits of the numberplate"))
       if numberplate3.isdigit():
           print("Verification 3 Fail")
           break
       elif numberplate3.isaplha():
           print("Verification Passed")
           start
   elif numberplate2.isalpha():
       print("Verification 2 Failed")
       break
elif numberplate1.isdigit():
   print("Return to the start")
   break
start = time.time() 
inp = input("Please press enter when car has left monitoring area\n>")
end = time.time()
print("Car took {:.2f} seconds ".format(end-start))
print("Car travelled at {:.2f} m/s. ".format(200/(end-start)))
```

---

The program will check the format of a numberplate, but I would also like for it to check for the length too. (It checks to see if it has a letter, number etc, but it needs to check for the length on each check)

If possible, a program that checks for the numberplate format would really help.
Checking for LETTER-LETTER-NUMBER-NUMBER LETTER-LETTER-LETTER (AB12 CDE) If not, I am fine with help on my current program

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you misspelled `'isaplha'` in one place; it should be `'isalpha'`. Also, have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: I just fixed that, I've sorted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is just a typo: You misspelled `'isaplha'`; it should be `'isalpha'`.

For your other question: You can make your program a whole lot simpler by using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) for matching the number plate, like this:

```
import re
while True:
    numberplate = input("Enter the numberplate: ").lower()
    if re.match("[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}", numberplate):
        print("Verification Success")
        break
    else:
        print("Verification Failed")
```

Here, the regular expression `"[a-z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z]{3}"` means "two letters, two digits, three letters".